Why is it not all azure app-insights metric appear in Grafana
I am setting up some Grafana dashboards which retrieve data from Azure. I have managed to setup most of the required panels but one that is eluding me is Authenticated Users.
So in azure we have app-test-UK-dev-euw-appinsights -> Metrics

And this returns accurate data in Azure

So over in Grafana I can see most of the Log-based metrics

And if I choose any of those I see data that matches what I see in Azure, all cool and froody so far. But what I cannot select from the pulldown list in Grafana is Users, it is simply not there.

Is this correct?
Why do some Log-based metrics appear and a few do not?
Is it me, am I missing something here?
Any thoughts please folks.

if the metric you are trying to display is not a Log-based metric, it may not be available in Grafana. The reason why the "Users" metric is not appearing in Grafana could be due to the fact that it is not a Log-based metric, but rather a metric collected by Azure Monitor Metrics. Grafana's Azure Monitor data source plugin retrieves data from Azure Monitor Metrics for numeric time series data from Azure resources

References:

Monitor your Azure services in Grafana
Gain insights into your app users’ activity


As mentioned in comments, some metrics, such as Authenticated Users, might not be exposed through the plugin.
Grafana uses the Azure Monitor data source plugin to retrieve metrics from Azure services.

However, this plugin might not support all types of metrics. Refer Supported metrics with Azure Monitor DataSource plugin for supported metrics.
Metrics like "Dependency calls", "Page views", etc are predefined and commonly available through Azure Monitor.
Custom metrics such as "Users, authenticated" require querying Azure Monitor Logs using KQL. Something like this-
customMetrics
| where name == "Users, authenticated"
| summarize Count = dcount(tenantId) by bin(timestamp, 1h)

References:

Monitor your Azure services in Grafana
Azure Monitor Metrics Troubleshoot
Log Analytics KQL

